# How to resolve "Insufficient Permission" error in Google Calendar API for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I'm trying to use Google Calendar API for Ruby and this is code that I took from the google console site. But when I tried to run this code, I got this error.

```
......rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client.rb:662:in `block (2 levels) in execute!': Insufficient Permission (Google::APIClient::ClientError)


require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storage'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storages/file_store'
require 'fileutils'

APPLICATION_NAME = 'Calendar API Quickstart'
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secret.json'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',
                             "calendar-api-quickstart.json")
#SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'


SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
def authorize
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(CREDENTIALS_PATH))

  file_store = Google::APIClient::FileStore.new(CREDENTIALS_PATH)
  storage = Google::APIClient::Storage.new(file_store)
  auth = storage.authorize

  if auth.nil? || (auth.expired? && auth.refresh_token.nil?)
    app_info = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
    flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new({
      :client_id => app_info.client_id,
     # :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback',

      :client_secret => app_info.client_secret,
      :scope => SCOPE})
    auth = flow.authorize(storage)
    puts "Credentials saved to #{CREDENTIALS_PATH}" unless auth.nil?
  end
  auth
end

# Initialize the API
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => APPLICATION_NAME)
calendar_api = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
client.authorization = authorize


=begin
# Fetch the next 10 events for the user
results = client.execute!(
  :api_method => calendar_api.events.list,
  :parameters => {
    :calendarId => 'primary',
    :maxResults => 10,
    :singleEvents => true,
    :orderBy => 'startTime',
    :timeMin => Time.now.iso8601 })

puts "Upcoming events:"
puts "No upcoming events found" if results.data.items.empty?
results.data.items.each do |event|
  start = event.start.date || event.start.date_time
  puts "- #{event.summary} (#{start})" 
  puts "- #{event.updated} (#{start})" 
#  puts "- #{event.accessRole} (#{start})" 


  ##여기에 뭔가 생기는군

end
=end

event = {
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => {
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end' => {
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence' => [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees' => [
    {'email' => 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email' => 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
  'reminders' => {
    'useDefault' => false,
    'overrides' => [
      {'method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60},
      {'method' => 'sms', 'minutes' => 10},
    ],
  },
}

results = client.execute!(
  :api_method => calendar_api.events.insert,
  :parameters => {
    :calendarId => 'primary'},
  :body_object => event)
event = results.data
puts "Event created: #{event.htmlLink}"
```

I copied the functioning part from the console site here. How can I allow the permission to use Calendar application?

For the basic read-only app, I was able to run the application because I have Calendar application enabled in the console setting but don't know how to proceed the next step. Please let me know how to solve this issue :)

Comment: Did you solve it? I can not find a solution. It works fine for *events.list* but not *events.insert*, same as your case.

Answer (score 0):

I was in trouble same to you. You should change two points below:

- Your application name is aimed to draw quick sample data by API. It is suitable to set your own application name. The name is one you registered in Google developer console.
- You should change `credentials path` to your own. The path you wrote is only for quick start sample.

`{File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',"calendar-api-quickstart.json"")} >>>
   {File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',"client_secret.json")}`